# Bash - Initialize variable to output of command "permission denied"

Tags: bash, variables, pipe

I'm writing a small bash script to get the number out of each file name. For example the file name `helloworld1.txt` would produce `1`.

When attempting to set the output to the variable `i` I get an error for each file.

```
line 5: 985.txt: Permission denied
```

If I just echo the command `echo $f | tr -dc '[0-9]'` rather than assign it to a variable, everything is good.

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *
do
        i=`$f | tr -dc '[0-9]'` // Permission denied.
        echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have missed echo here. The line

```
i=`$f | tr -dc '[0-9]'`
```

should be

```
i=`echo $f | tr -dc '[0-9]'`
```

Comment: How embarrassing! Thanks very much!

Comment: The ` \``backtick\`` ` syntax is obsolete; in the current millennium, the recommended syntax is `i=$(echo "$f" | tr -dc '0-9')`. Notice also the use of proper quoting around the variable, and the absence of square brackets in the `tr` command.

Answer (score 0):

The line in the loop without a subshell, pipe and additional process per file:

```
i=${f//[^0-9]/}
```

The parameter substitution removes all non-digits.